# a nginx module connecting zookeeper

Tags: nginx, apache-zookeeper

I developed a nginx module (on linux) which connects zookeeper(on windows 7), and set a watcher by get method.But I find, the  callback is not be called, when I change the data of node on windows.I change the data of node on nginx module, It can call  the callback.I'm puzzled about the quetion.

By debugging, I find the threads that created on zookeeper init were killed by nginx.When I debug by gdb with 'info threads', it only shows one thread, but it should be three threads.Why is this and how can I solve it?

This is the code:https://github.com/B12040331/nginx-zookeeper

Comment: You definitely should provide more info about how your module is organized.

Comment: Thank you. By debuging, I find the problem is that, niginx killing the threads(do_io and do_completion) created by zookeeper.But I dont't know the reason and the solution.The code is in github, this is the link:https://github.com/B12040331/nginx-zookeeper.